# OWIN Web Api - responses suddenly return 404 on requests that recently returned 200

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin

**I've edited my question with some more relevant information.**

I have a `Owin Web-Api` site that is hosted on `IIS`.

The application has a single controller with 2 actions.
The application works well. All actions return valid results.

When the application pool is recycled, the app starts returning 404's.
Only rebuilding the bin directory (I'm currently working locally) will revive the application (stop\start on the application pool doesn't do anything positive).

This is how my *Startup.cs* looks like:

```
var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfiguration.Register(httpConfiguration); // will show it's content later

appBuilder.UseRequestScopeContext(); // Third party OwinRequestScopeContext
appBuilder.Use<IOCContainerMiddleware>(); // Custom middleware that creates an IOC container per request and disposes it at the end of the request

appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
```

*WebApiConfiguration.Register*:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) },
defaults: null);

ConfigureDependencyResolver(config); // Custom dependency resolver that uses the IOC container from above
```

Comment: Please show us the URL for a working and non-working request.

Comment: @mjwills - It's the exact same request (url, headers, body). That's why it's driving me crazy..

Comment: I guess, you host your app in IIS. Does this behavior happen after the application is recycled by IIS (check the recycling settings)?

Comment: How do you know that the application was not suddenly shutdown? There might be idle timeout or an application crash. Try to add explicit log in the beginning of the startup method and check that you have just one startup event. Also, check Windows Event log for related error events. If you keep calling your app, let's say every 30 sec, do you have same behavior?

Comment: @SergeyL - Regarding the recycling, I've checked the event log.
About adding the logs, that's what I'm doing right now adding them globally and between middlewares.
When the app works, it can serve request fluently. Then I stop sending it requests for a couple of minutes and on the next requests, I receive a 404 response until a rebuild the application (I working locally).

Comment: Does only the first request after timeout fail or all requests after timeout?

Comment: @SergeyL - All.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166628/discussion-between-sergey-l-and-amir-popovich).

Comment: @SergeyL - Thanks for your help. FYI, I found the issue and posted a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

My Startup class is located on an external dll, that is referenced to my application (and exists in my bin folder).

I add the `"owin:appStartup"` key inside my `appSettings` section inside my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="WebApiServicePrototype.Startup.ServiceStartup, WebApiServicePrototype" />
</appSettings>
```

When the `owin:appStartup` key pointed to an external dll it worked, until the application's app pool got recycled (I'm hosting on IIS), and then started to throw 404 results.

When the `owin:appStartup` pointed to a Startup class that existed in the current application's dll, everything worked OK.

So for now, I've created a dummy adapter on the application's dll and assign the `owin:appStartup` to point to it.

I'm not sure if this is by design or not.

Comment: To avoid such problems in the future (caused by moving or renaming your startup class) I recommend using the [Startup class detection via OwinStartup Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection)

Comment: But the startup class is shared by multiple services and therefore is located in an external assembly.To me, this seems like this is a bug.